# gateway is not pingable /etc/networ/interfaces

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet, ip

I have a raspberry pi and modem connected to the network. I add the following lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1 
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    metric 0

auto wwan0
iface wwan0 inet static
    address 177.177.8.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 177.177.8.1
    metric 100
```

when I `ping 177.177.8.1` which is the gateway for modem network it is not pinging the screen stuck at

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping 177.177.8.1
PING 177.177.8.1 (177.177.8.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

at `eth0` I have an IP camera whose ip is `192.168.1.10` which is pingable in the network but the gateway for `wwan0` is not pinging so I am not able to connect to my modem network. I check the syntax changing matric values and assigned `wwan0` same gateway and IP but not working. here is the result of `ifconfig`

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether dc:a6:32:11:ff:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 92  bytes 8202 (8.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 92  bytes 8202 (8.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wwan0: flags=4240<POINTOPOINT,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 177.177.8.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 177.177.8.5
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17  bytes 2075 (2.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: The `/etc/network/interfaces` mechanism is deprecated. I suggest that you use netplan. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you, How can I assign static IP using netplan

Comment: Please see the example templates at /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples. Then follow with: `sudo netplan generate` and: `sudo netplan apply`.